# OpenWeatherMap Weather returns null

Tags: arduino, openweathermap

I am trying to build a small weather station but when i try to read the weather from the Json it allways gets null.
I'm using an esp8266 with the <Arduino_JSON.h> Library.

```
 jsonBuffer = httpGETRequest(serverPath.c_str());
    myObject = JSON.parse(jsonBuffer);
    if (JSON.typeof(myObject) == "undefined") {
      Serial.println("Parsing input failed!");
      return;
    }

    Serial.print("JSON object = ");
    Serial.println(myObject);

    lcd.clear();
    int temp =int(myObject["main"]["temp"]);
    lcd.print(temp-273);
    lcd.print("K ");
    lcd.print(myObject["main"]["pressure"]);
    lcd.print("hPa ");
    lcd.print(myObject["main"]["humidity"]);
    lcd.print("%");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(myObject["wind"]["speed"]);
    lcd.print("m/s ");
    lcd.print(myObject["weather"]["main"]);
```

a example Json:
{"coord":{"lon":13.4105,"lat":52.5244},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":278.52,"feels_like":274.25,"temp_min":275.93,"temp_max":280.36,"pressure":1004,"humidity":67},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.69,"deg":250},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1679934901,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2011538,"country":"DE","sunrise":1679892806,"sunset":1679938206},"timezone":7200,"id":2950159,"name":"Berlin","cod":200}

Comment: What version of ArduinoJson you are using? V5 or V6? Not sure where you get the idea on the way of deserialising the json object. I will suggest you use the [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/#/step1) to help you to generate the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I found another solution: The weather is passed as an array, so I just need to add an Index.

Answer (score 0):

I use openWeather too but with JSON_Decoder.h : it works fine. That's not answer you would like but another method.
This is the openweather part of my code :

```
#include <JSON_Decoder.h>
#include <OpenWeather.h>

OW_Weather ow;

String api_key = "da2962d8_ETC...ETC...";
String latitude =  "46.099998";
String longitude = "5.33333";
String units = "metric";
String language = "fr";

void printCurrentWeather(boolean show) {
  OW_current *current = new OW_current;
  OW_hourly *hourly = new OW_hourly;
  OW_daily  *daily = new OW_daily;

  ow.getForecast(current, hourly, daily, api_key, latitude, longitude, units, language);

  if (current)
  {
    H1 = Ntp.convertToLocal(current->sunrise);
    H2 = Ntp.convertToLocal(current->sunset);
    T = current->temp;
    TR = current->feels_like;
    H = current->humidity;
    P = current->pressure;
    WS = current->wind_speed;
    WG = current->wind_gust;
  }
}
```

hope it will help !